# what is needed for printable psd file in Photoshop?

Tags: business

what is needed for printable psd file in Photoshop?
i need printable file .
but i made it with rgb color mode and wants to convert into a printable copy.[image: i want to convert this file]

Comment: ...You need a printer, the printer drivers, and if using a .PSD then some piece of software that can open said .PSD. I don't think this is what you're after though so could you [edit] the question to better explain the problem.

Comment: printable file usually means 300dpi, CMYK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the RGB colors to CMYK colors in Photoshop with:

`Image` > `Mode` > `CMYK Color`

Change the DPI to 300 in Photoshop with:

`Image` > `Image Size...`

In the Image Size settings:

Change `Resolution` to `300 Pixels/Inch`

Uncheck `Resample Image` if it's checked, so your image stays the same size (pixel dimensions stay the same).

Now `File` > `Save As...`

Change `Format` to `Photoshop PDF`.

---

**Note that your file has colors on the edges and requires a 3 mm Bleed on it so that you get no white edges after cutting the edges.**

This can't be done with Photoshop and would require Adobe InDesign. However, you could cut it a bit on the colored edges so that the business cards get a little smaller. You lose size but have no white edges (which is why bleed is required).

Comment: For bleed the OP could make the document larger and then add cut marks to incorporate the required bleed (add about 35 pixels to each side; or 70 pixels to height and width respectively).

Comment: Agreed, although it would only require 11 pixels as that's about equal to 3 mm. I as a Desktop Publisher have only learned this with Adobe InDesign and Adobe Illustrator, haha.

Comment: I just took 300dpi/8 (1/8 inch bleed, each side); which is probably overkill for a business card.